# How to access google drive from our meteor application?

Tags: meteor, google-drive-api

I am building a meteor application.In many instances i need to access google service such as sharing,uploading files etc.

Gone through Google's guide, but some area is not clear.

Created a new project,then in overview enabled drive API.
Created Credentials-->Service Account Key--->App Engine.

Downloaded the private key.

And in my application there is a button when clicked it should access the google services such as if the button is intended for file sharing then it should access google's share service or if it is intended for file uploading then it should access google's upload to drive service and similarly I want to view the files uploaded to google drive in my application.

Somebody help me with the code since I am very new to meteor and this I am finding difficulty in developing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs#prerequisites) Google provided. Use it as a stepping stone to familiarize yourself on the behavior, errors, best practices in using the api.

Here is the sample code for listing the file names and IDs:

```
/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  var service = google.drive('v3');
  service.files.list({
    auth: auth,
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var files = response.files;
    if (files.length == 0) {
      console.log('No files found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Files:');
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        console.log('%s (%s)', file.name, file.id);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**NOTE**: Follow the prerequisite.

- [Enable the Drive Platform](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/enable-sdk#enable_the_drive_api)
- [Authorizing Your App with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth)

**Further Readings that will help you with google integration**

- [Google Developers Console help documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud#topic=3340599)
- [Google APIs Client for Node.js documentation](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#google-apis-nodejs-client)
- [Drive REST API reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/)

**Tutorials**

Here is a tutorial for implementation of Google OAuth 2.0 for server-to-server interactions for [Meteor](https://github.com/jagi/meteor-google-oauth-jwt). You can also using JavaScript application that makes requests to the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js).

Comment: Thanks :) Let me check